# Error while eval() pointer to the property as an instance of class

Tags: php, error-handling, eval, factory-pattern

I'm using factory pattern, and the number of parameters need to inject is big, and I don't want to assign every single object.

So I wrote this code to assign them like this:

```
class abc {
    function __construct() 
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        foreach ($args as $a) {
            eval("\$this->$a = \$a;");
            // my purpose code to execute : $this->db = $db;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if the the arguments are strings, instead if it's a instance of class, this error shows up:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class db could not be converted to
>   string in

Comment: is that `->$a` needed? because it must be a string

Comment: @JOUM the purpose is assign class properties as agrument object, string ... any kind of agrument

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, it's about 5-10. Injecting an array of object still get you to write code to assign every single agrument as class's properties. Many class use them and i don't want to repeat the code

Comment: Sorry that makes no sense, because you have to give a propertie a name. How will you access them later currently? And sidenote: EVAL is EVIL